# What's the most efficient and cleanest way to reassemble different types of AL activities on a single logsheet?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

By default, the Adventurers League logsheet has the syntax needed to properly log a game that you participated to as a player.

But I personally also DM (putting all the XP I get from it on the character I play), and sometimes do downtime trading (for said character).

Right now, I've been having the habit of writing these non-player activities (DMing & trading) on the back of my player logsheets, as the syntax of said logsheets is not made for these other activities. The result is, of course, quite messy, and would be hard to follow by an eventual DM who would want to look it up. Of course, I can have a dm logsheet and trading logsheet separately, but I think it can still be confusing, especially if your player logsheet's experienxe suddenly jumps a bunch because of dm xp rewards.

So, what would be the most efficient and cleanest way to record multiple types of AL activities, all affecting the same character ? Would it be to put it in a single logsheet but be creative with the default syntax ? Or to invent a new (or use an existing more complex) logsheet syntax ?

(I intend to rewrite my logsheets in a cleaner way once I have the optimal way of presenting the combined info)

Answer (score 5):

### Facts

WotC and DDAL provide an example log sheet, and many people use it, but there is no required or standardized log sheet. As long as you record the values in a clear way that you can understand and explain to others with minimal effort, you're allowed to come up with your own method.

### Character Logs

Personally, my characters are recorded on logsheets created by [More Purple More Better](http://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?author=morepurplemorebetter) and available on the DMs Guild. Technically, I get mine through MPMB's Patreon integrated into the character sheet I use, but the standalone log sheets work the same way.

When I apply DM experience, I simply create an entry with "DM Rewards" as the name of the "adventure", and sum up the XP, GP, DT, Renown, and magic item count as normal. I put my own name and DCI number in as the DM, and include the date. If I'm applying multiple awards at once, I use the notes fields to track specific entries<sup>1</sup>.

Trading goes the same way. Create an entry with "Item Trading", then use the notes field to record who you traded with. Don't forget to mark down what you traded away, what you received, and the other player's real name and DCI number. I tend to put name and DCI in notes, but you could put it in the DM field, too.

Between-session purchase?... Same thing. I generally list the DM as N/A in this case, but you could list yourself. Money where it belongs, the specifics of what you bought to the side.

### DM Logs

For DM rewards, I log them in an Excel spreadsheet. I track the module name and all the other particulars. I use Excel because I have it set up to automatically calculate basic DM rewards by supplying it the length and APL, and I made it smart enough to recognize kickers like "Cursed DM" and "Ethereal DM". I also track when I earned it, and which character I applied it to. I don't track when I applied it, because the character log records that.

### TLDR

You do you, as long as you can explain it clearly.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'll look into providing some sample screen captures later tonight.</sub>

Comment: +1 the moment I hit "More Purple More Better". I know others who enjoy adventurersleaguelog.org better, but I've been happiest with MPMB.

Comment: @Nitsua60 I use a Microsoft Surface for all my gaming needs, and while it does have built-in LTE, I like to keep things local. Online access is not 100% fast or reliable, especially in convention centers and hotels.